# How to find all forms of the fraction that would be in between two other fractions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, fractions

I've been going through lots of my math textbooks, and I'm able to solve a lot of them using some specific method or formula. But there's one problem I've come across quite a few times that I just couldn't figure out how to do. One example is...

> Suppose that $\frac {4}{2001} < \frac {a}{a+b} < \frac {5}{2001}$. Compute the number of different possible integer values that $\frac {b}{a}$ can take on.

Does anyone know a reliable method to do these kind of these problems, or even better, a formula? My best attempts have been to manually list out all of the possibilities, and it would really help if someone could explain a good way to do these kind of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the inequality you are trying to satisfy is the same as
$$\frac{2001}{4} > \frac{a+b}{a} > \frac{2001}{5}.$$

Comment: I have figured that out already, but I'm not quite sure where to go from there.

Comment: Next hint: $\frac{a+b}{a} = 1 + \frac{b}{a}$.  So you are, in effect, asking how many integers are between $\frac{2001}{4}$ and $\frac{2001}{5}$.  You can compute both those numbers exactly...

Comment: So all of the numbers between (and including) $\floor (\frac {2001}{4})$ and $\ceil (\frac {2001}{5})$. Which should amount to 100?

Comment: @Edwards: Yes, exactly.

Comment: I'm currently stuck at $\frac{1997}{4}>\frac{b}{a}>\frac{1996}{5}$ If i take the difference I get $100.05$, I could've solved this problem if it weren't in fractions.

Comment: @LazyJoeShow: So convert $1997/4$ and $1996/5$ to decimals, if that makes things easier for you.  That should make it clear which integers are in between the two.

Comment: @LazyJoeShow: Just subtracting the numbers won't quite answer the question, because you can't tell from the difference of two numbers alone how many integers are between them.  Consider $1.8$ and $3.2$, versus $4.1$ and $5.5$.  Both pairs have a difference of $1.4$, yet there are two integers between $1.8$ and $3.2$, and only one integer between $4.1$ and $5.5$.

Comment: I've understood your point, I replied to your old comment but this new one clarified things (hence deleted it).